OpenJDK TLS version
My application build of java springboot using openJDK 11 which is from here.
problem is i have tried several ways to hardcode the tls version.
First thing i noticed using jdk debug comments is, from class "o.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig" in log message i can see this info

The protocol [TLSv1.2] was added to the list of protocols on the SSLHostConfig named [default]. Check if a +/- prefix is missing.

for this have hardcode in application properties & written some custome configuration class for tomcat server, none were worked out & tried some other ways also, none of the attempts were successfully.
below is my application properties:
#javax.net.ssl.protocol=+TLSv1.3
#java.security.properties.jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2
#jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2
#management.server.ssl.enabled=true

#management.server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.3
#server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.jks

#server.ssl.key-store-password=

#server.ssl.key-password=
#server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
#server.ssl.trust-store=src/main/resources/truststore.jks

#server.ssl.trust-store-password=
#server.ssl.enabled=true
#server.ssl.enabled-protocols=+TLSv1.3
#server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
#server.tomcat.ssl.enabled-protocols=+TLSv1.3
#server.ssl.key-alias=1

Have tried all possible ways as of my knowledge, none were good results. one intresting thing is, while handshake itself it's using 1.2 & you can see in logs,
2024-07-05 09:38:19.571  INFO 28872 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2024-07-05 09:38:19.571 GMT|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
2024-07-05 09:38:19.756  INFO 28872 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}`
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|task-1|2024-07-05 09:38:19.888 GMT|HandshakeContext.java:296|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|task-1|2024-07-05 09:38:19.889 GMT|HandshakeContext.java:296|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|12|task-1|2024-07-05 09:38:19.912 GMT|ServerNameExtension.java:261|Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|task-1|2024-07-05 09:38:19.912 GMT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name

this is above message while handshake. My expectation is my application should use 1.3 as priority & fall back to 1.2 if the server didn't support 1.3.

Your syntax for the value of server.ssl.enabled-protocols for Tomcat in SpringBoot is wrong as indicated in the error message. Use the following to limit to 1.3 & 1.2:
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=+TLSv1.3+TLSv1.2-TLSv1.1-TLSv1.0


Hi John , have tried this solution, unfortunately, it couldn't resolve the issue.

What exactly is the error when you apply this? Or what does non-resolve look like, eg use of 1.2 when 1.3 available both ends?

There is no error at all, before tomcat initializing some other componets started negotiating using 1.2.
main] o.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil   : The [protocols] that are active are : [[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]]   ****
2024-07-11 10:41:35.335 DEBUG 12571 --- [ main] u.n.o.c.OpenSSLCipherConfigurationParser : Ciphers used: [TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,]

2024-07-11 10:41:35.335 DEBUG 12571 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil   : The [ciphers] that are active are : [[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]]

I guess there is no such thing as "1.3 as priority & fall back to 1.2 if the server didn't support 1.3." If 1.2 is open then 1.2 can be used even if the correspondent has 1.3 also.

thanks for correcting my understanding, in my application problem here my server  and client supports 1.3, yet it's using 1.2 as default one & making handshake

@Ninjavas Read this:  https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art080
